# Typelite POCO Class Generation

Tags: typescript, typelite

Is it possible for Typelite to generate a TypeScript class instead of an interface? Something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
export class Person
{
    constructor() {}
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}
```

I'm not looking for any functionality in the generated classes, only an easier way to be able to instantiate classes clientside without having to initialize the entire interface.

For example, I would prefer being able to do this:

```
var person = new Person();
```

Instead of

```
var person = {
    FirstName: null,
    LastName: null
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I did was make a simple adjustment to the tt file, saves you from compiling your own typelite:

```
<#= definitions.ToString()
.Replace("interface", "export class")
.Replace("declare module", "module") #>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. It does mean I will need to generate 2 files since I am only interested in this happening on specific classes.

Comment: Where do I make this change? Can you share your TypeLite.Net4.tt class

Answer (score 5):

This feature is supported by [Reinforced.Typings](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings).

Using attribute

```
[TsClass]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

or [fluent call](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Fluent-configuration)

```
public class Configuration
{
    public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder) 
    {
            builder
                .ExportAsClass<Person>()
                .WithPublicProperties();
    }
}
```

will produce following to the output file:

```
namespace MyApp {
    export class User
    {
        public FirstName: string;
        public LastName : string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this scenario isn't supported right now.

I have never missed such feature, because classes usually have some methods, so it didn't make a sense to me. But feel free to fiddle with the source ('TsGenerator.cs'), it shouldn't be too difficult to generate classes instead of interfaces if you don't require any methods in the classes.

Comment: Thanks. For me it makes sense to generate a class, where all properties have private setters and are initialized from constructor. In this way it will be easier to escape initialize errors on client side. But not sure if it's ever possible.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but the classes can't have any behaviour (like methods) because every time you run TypeLite your custom code get lost. If TypeScript has support for something like partial classes I will add support for generating classes, but I'm not aware of such concept TypeScript.

Comment: For me there's no any need in methods since in my opinion it would be a  bad practice to add behavior to DTOs. Just a class with ctor

Comment: My use case is simply for DTOs with no behavior. I literally just want to instantiate a class that satisfies the interface without having to recreate what Typelite already does so nicely for me. I would fully expect to have to attach behavior or values through some other means.

Comment: This sounds like a common request. Is there a place to make such feature requests to litesolutions.net?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issues?status=new&status=open ... feature requests with pull requests are preferred ;-)

Comment: FYI for others this feature request is  @ https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issues/66/ability-to-create-class-definition-instead

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Flores' answer above, in the latest version of TypeLite (1.8.4 as of right now), you can modify the call to ts.Generate(...) as follows:

```
<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties)
    .Replace("interface", "export class")
    .Replace("declare module", "module") #>
```

Full Transform:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)MyAssembly.dll" #>

<#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
<#@output extension=".d.ts"#>

<#@include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
<# var manager = Manager.Create(Host, GenerationEnvironment); #>

<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
    .WithReference("Enums.ts")
    .ForLoadedAssemblies();
#>

<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties)
    .Replace("interface", "export class")
    .Replace("declare module", "module") #>

<# manager.StartNewFile("Enums.ts"); #>
<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Enums) #>
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>
<# manager.Process(true); #>
```